# Drupal 7: Как изменить атрибуты в форме?

Tags: cms, drupal

Допустим форма входа:`<form action="/user/login" method="post" id="user-login" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>` Каким образом я могу в форме: `<form></form>` добавлять или убирать или менять атрибуты?

Моя форма имеет action="/user/login", но я хотел бы заменить на action-xhr="/user/login".

"Форма с action="/user/login" по умолчанию"
[image: Форма с action="/user/login" по умолчанию]

---

"Форма с action-xhr="/user/login" которую необходимо реализовать"

[image: Форма с action-xhr="/user/login" которую необходимо реализовать]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации потребуется хук `_form_alter();`
В теме оформления (в которой необходимо изменить форму входа) добавляем хук в template.php

```
function имятемы_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $user_login) {
  $form['#attributes']['action-xhr'] = "/user/login";
}
```